# Export binary truetype with Python 3.4

Tags: python, file, binary, export, truetype

I would like to export a truetype file with my python program. According to the specification, a truetype file consists of tables that may contain any of the following data types:

```
Data type   Description
BYTE    8-bit unsigned integer.
CHAR    8-bit signed integer.
USHORT  16-bit unsigned integer.
SHORT   16-bit signed integer.
ULONG   32-bit unsigned integer.
LONG    32-bit signed integer.
FIXED   32-bit signed fixed-point number (16.16)
FUNIT   Smallest measurable distance in the em space.
FWORD   16-bit signed integer (SHORT) that describes a quantity in FUnits.
UFWORD  Unsigned 16-bit integer (USHORT) that describes a quantity in FUnits. 
F2DOT14 16-bit signed fixed number with the low 14 bits of fraction (2.14).
```

How would I go about writing this kind of data to a file?

edit: What I have so far is this:

```
s.data = ''
s.data += '{0:016}'.format(10)
```

To write the number 10 as a 16-bit unsigned int. However, I cannot do

```
s.file = open('test.ttf', 'wb')
s.file.write(s.data)
```

as this raises a

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
    s.data = []
    s.data.append('{0:016b}'.format(someint))
    f = open('test.ttf', 'wb')
    bytearray = array.array('B')
    for b in s.data:
        b1 = int(b[:16], 2)
        bytearray.append(b1)
        if len(b)>16:
            b2 = int(b[16:], 2)
            bytearray.append(b2)
    bytearray.tofile(f)
    f.close()
```

And it looks like it works.